# Include filenames in readOGR batch reading

Tags: r, purrr, rgdal

I am working with shapefiles where the location id data is only available in the folder name. I wrote the following code to read the files in as a batch, but I am struggling with how to include the location id folder name in a column as well.

```
folders <- list.dirs(path = "/home/username/foldername/location_id", 
full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

all_files <- function(folder) {
  out<-readOGR(dsn = paste0(folder), layer = "SAMENAME", verbose = TRUE)
    return(out)
}

my_shapefiles <- purrr::map(folders, safely(all_files))
```

Comment: Hi @Nazer, I'm glad I was able to help solve your problem. Just curious about your edit... were you trying to get "folder2" or "foldername" from `folder`?

Comment: @Skaqqs, "folder2" contains the id info I need. I'll edit it to make that more clear. Bad choice of labels by me.

Comment: Ok thanks! I edited the regex in my answer accordingly. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two approaches:

```
folder <- "/home/username/foldername/folder2"

basename(folder)
#> [1] "folder2"
gsub(".*\\/(.*)$", "\\1", folder)
#> [1] "folder2"
```

Therefore, you could modify your function like this:

```
all_files <- function(folder) {
  out <- readOGR(dsn = paste0(folder), layer = "SAMENAME", verbose = TRUE)
  out$id <- basename(folder)
    return(out)
}
```

Created on 2021-10-18 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)